# Nothing showing up in html

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website for fun, and I'm stuck now after creating a sticky navbar. Nothing I type shows up after making the navbar and just shows a black screen. My code is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 

</head>


 <body>
  <div id="navbar">
      <img src="images/logo.png" href="#default" 
 id="logo"></img>
      <div id="navbar-right">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#`enter code here`">Solutions</a>
        <a href="#">Promotions</a>
        <a href="#">Brochure</a>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h1> Promotions</h1>
    </div>
  </body>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navbar.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

anything after the navbar, specifically the h1 promotion is not showing up.
below is my css code

```
 /*This is for the home page*/
  * {box-sizing: border-box;}
  body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-color: #161616;
  }

#navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #161616;
padding: 30px 50px;
transition: 0.4s;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
z-index: 99;
}

#navbar a {
float: left;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: Montserrat;
line-height: 25px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

 #navbar #logo {
 /*font-size: 35px;
 font-weight: bold;*/
 width: 20%;
 height: auto;
 transition: 0.4s;
 }



#navbar a.active {
background-color: dodgerblue;
color: white;
}*/

#navbar-right {
float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
#navbar {
padding: 20px 10px !important;
}
#navbar a {
float: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
#navbar-right {
float: none;
}

}

.main-section h1{
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
 }
```

I'm running node server.js and trying to host it on my PC. After running it, I realise that the header does not come up nor does anything comes up. I can't seem to understand what's the problem. Thanks for any insights that may be helpful.

Comment: your link tag for your stylesheet is open

Comment: allso you dont need a `</img>` tag

Answer (score 4):

I pasted your code into a CodePen (https://codepen.io/kenbellows/pen/dwpQmm) and based on that alone, your problem is that the `<h1>` is hidden behind the fixed `<nav>` element. Since the navbar has a background color, and since the `<h1>` is not fixed and is thus sitting right at the top, the navbar covers the `<h1>`'s content.

If you fix the classname on the `.container` div to `main-section` to match the CSS and give it a large top margin, the header is pushed below the navbar and becomes visible: https://codepen.io/kenbellows/pen/gZwQdq

A little beside the point, but instead of `position: fixed;`, I'd recommend looking into `position: sticky;`. It has pretty solid support at this point, but do mind your browser requirements, as it's still a somewhat new feature.

Here's another version of the original code that merely swaps `position: absolute` for `position: sticky`, *without* adding a top margin to the main section: https://codepen.io/kenbellows/pen/LMRXvm

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
```

You have left your link tag open

Answer (score -1):

- link your css file properly in link tag
- script should be at end of body tag not after closing body tag

```css
/*This is for the home page*/
  * {box-sizing: border-box;}
  body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-color: #161616;
  }

#navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #161616;
padding: 30px 50px;
transition: 0.4s;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
z-index: 99;
}

#navbar a {
float: left;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: Montserrat;
line-height: 25px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

 #navbar #logo {
 /*font-size: 35px;
 font-weight: bold;*/
 width: 20%;
 height: auto;
 transition: 0.4s;
 }



#navbar a.active {
background-color: dodgerblue;
color: white;
}*/

#navbar-right {
float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
#navbar {
padding: 20px 10px !important;
}
#navbar a {
float: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
#navbar-right {
float: none;
}

}

.main-section h1{
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" >

</head>


 <body>
  <div id="navbar">
      <img src="images/logo.png" href="#default" 
 id="logo"></img>
      <div id="navbar-right">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#`enter code here`">Solutions</a>
        <a href="#">Promotions</a>
        <a href="#">Brochure</a>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h1> Promotions</h1>
    </div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navbar.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: I was editing answer so before giving negative point plz wait for 2 mins